# Installation Guide For Drupal with Nginx on Fedora 19

Tags: nginx, drupal-7, fedora

How to install drupal with nginx on fedora 19 ? Somebody please help . I am an absolute beginner to drupal and nginx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install nginx, you can just run `sudo yum install nginx` in the terminal.

Fedora has a very helpful [wiki page](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_install_Drupal) that details the steps on how to install Drupal.
At step no. 7 when it asks you to start Apache server, you can run nginx server instead by running `service nginx start`.